# what were taxes like during Solomon's time? (According to Judaism)

Tags: history, king-solomon, taxes

I know there was terumah (10%) which went to kohanim and maaser ani (9% every other year to poor) + maaser sheni, which isn't exactly a tax but you had to spend it in Jerusalem. Where did non-Temple state expenses come from? What other taxes/corvees were there?

I do remember something about chests at the temple that went to pay for marking graves

Comment: I Kings 12 will be of interest.

Comment: What defines a tax? Beis Din is empowered to extricate money from individuals for specific purposes (hefker beis din hefker), but that is vastly different from a monarchical tax...

Comment: That is good. Include it in your answer.